# Sumar los valores de 2 diccionarios

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero sumar los valores de 2 diccionarios

```
dict1={0: [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0], 1: [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3], 2: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
dict2={0: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0], 1: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 2: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

he probado así:

```
dict2.update(dict1)

print( dict2)
```

pero no lo consigo,yo el resultado que quiero por suma seria esta:

dict3={0: [1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4, 0], 1: [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3], 2: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

¿como se sumaria de esta forma?

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, `dict.update` no funciona porque lo que hace es tomar las parejas clave: valor del diccionario recibido como argumento, si la clave no existe en el original la agrega, **si existe substituye su valor por el valor que tiene en el diccionario pasado como argumento** (actualiza, no suma). El otro problema es que (a diferencia de `numpy.ndarray`, la suma de listas equivale a concatenar no a sumar elemento por elemento a lo largo de la lista):

> ```
> >>> a = [1, 2, 3]
> >>> b = [4, 5, 6]
> >>> a + b 
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>
> >>> import numpy as np
> >>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
> >>> b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
> >>> a + b 
> array([5, 7, 9])
> ```

Una forma general de hacer esto, sin importar si alguna de las claves falta en uno de los diccionarios o si una de las sublistas es más larga o corta que la otra es combinar `itertools.zip_longest` con `dict.get:`

```
from itertools import zip_longest

dict1 = {0: [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0], 1: [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3], 2: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
dict2 = {0: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0], 1: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 2: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

dict_res = {
    key: [v1 + v2 for v1, v2 in zip_longest(
              dict1.get(key, ()), dict2.get(key, ()), fillvalue=0
              )] for key in dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()}
```

> ```
> >>> dict_res
>
> {0: [1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4, 0],
>  1: [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3],
>  2: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
> ```

```
from itertools import zip_longest

dict1 = {0: [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 3]}
dict2 = {0: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0], 1: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

dict_res = {
    key: [v1 + v2 for v1, v2 in zip_longest(
              dict1.get(key, ()), dict2.get(key, ()), fillvalue=0
              )] for key in dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()}
```

> ```
> >>> dict_res
> {0: [1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4, 0, 3], 1: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
> ```

Ante datos faltantes se asume 0 por defecto en este caso.

Si alguien se confunde con las expresiones generadoras, lo anterior es equivalente a:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

dict1 = {0: [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0], 1: [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3], 2: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
dict2 = {0: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0], 1: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 2: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

dict_res = {}
for key in dict1.keys() | dict2.keys():
    sum_list = [] 
    for v1, v2 in zip_longest(dict1.get(key, ()), dict2.get(key, ()), fillvalue=0):
        sum_list.append(v1 + v2)
    dict_res[key] = sum_list
```

Por último, podemos generalizarlo para cualquier número de diccionarios usando una función:

```
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Set, TypeVar
from itertools import zip_longest


S = TypeVar("S", int, float)
DictT = Dict[Any, List[S]]


def dict_sublists_vector_sum(*dicts: DictT) -> DictT:
    """
    Agrupa todos los diccionarios sumando las listas con claves
    iguales en varios diccionarios. La suma se lleva as sumando los elementos
    en el mismo índice de cada lista con claves comunes.

    Los diccionarios pueden tener claves no comunes.
    Las listas (valores) pueden tener distinta longitud.
    Se asume 0 (neutro para la suma) como valor por defecto.

    Parámetros
    ----------
    *dicts: DictT
        Número indeterminado de diccionarios con listas de
        floats o enteros como valores.

    Retorno
    -------
    DictT
        Nuevo diccionario resultado de la agrupación.

    Ejemplo
    -------

    >>> dict1 = {0: [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0], 1: [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3]}
    >>> dict2 = {0: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 1: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7]}
    >>> dict3 = {2: [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0]}

    >>> dict_sublists_vector_sum(dict1, dict2, dict3)
    {0: [1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0],
     1: [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 7],
     2: [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0]}
    """

    keys: Set[Any] = set()
    for dic in dicts:
        keys.update(dic.keys())
    res = {key: [sum(items) for items in zip_longest(
              *(dic.get(key, ()) for dic in dicts), fillvalue=0
               )] for key in keys}
    return res
```

> ```
> >>> dict1 = {0: [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0], 1: [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3]}
> >>> dict2 = {0: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 1: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7]}
> >>> dict3 = {2: [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0]}
>
> >>> dict_sublists_vector_sum(dict1, dict2, dict3)
> {0: [1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0],
>  1: [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 7],
>  2: [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0]}
> ```

Comment: Genial como siempre! gracias

Answer (score 3):

Si partes de la base de que las keys iguales de ambos diccionarios tienen el mismo número de elementos, esta solución debería funcionar:

```
dict1={0: [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0], 1: [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3], 2: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
dict2={0: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0], 1: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 2: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

new_dict = {}
for key, value in dict1.items():
  sum_array = [(dict1[key][i] + dict2[key][i]) for i, ele in enumerate(value)]
  new_dict.setdefault(key, sum_array)

print(new_dict)
```

El resultado es:

```
{0: [1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4, 0], 1: [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3], 2: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Implementación con Python vainilla.

Debido a que no hay una manera directa para hacer esto, tendrás que hacerlo iterando sobre los objetos, el resultado sería algo así:

```py
dict1 = {
    0: [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0], 
    1: [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3], 
    2: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}

dict2 = {
    0: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0], 
    1: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    2: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}

assert dict1.keys() == dict2().keys()

resultado = {
    k: [
        v[i] + dict2[k][i] for i in range(len(v))
    ] for k, v in dict1.items()
}

print(resultado)
{
    0: [1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4, 0],
    1: [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3],
    2: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

Esto te va a dar el resultado que esperas, pero debes mantener la consistencia de la información, que las listas en cada clave tengan siempre la misma longitud, que las claves de cada diccionario coincidan con el otro.

### Implementación con Pandas

Pandas es una librería utilizada para el análisis de datos, te permite generar DataFrames a partir de múltiples fuentes (SQL, CSV, Diccionarios, numpy Arrays, Listas de Listas, entre otros).

Dada su naturaleza y origen, pandas es ideal para operaciones como estas, en este caso el código quedaría algo así.

```py
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {
    0: [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0], 
    1: [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3], 
    2: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}

dict2 = {
    0: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0], 
    1: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    2: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2)

res = df1 + df2

# Este es el dataframe resultado, lo puedes regresar a diccionario con
# res.to_dict()
   0  1  2
0  1  2  0
1  0  1  0
2  3  1  1
3  1  0  1
4  3  1  0
5  0  0  0
6  4  1  0
7  0  3  0
```